# Which command to use for "compiling" a new NPM project?

Tags: javascript, npm

I'm making a simple JS website using Three.js. I started my project this way:

```
$ npm init
$ npm install three
```

Where should I write my code that uses `Three.js`, and what is the `npm` command I should run to "compile" my script for something to drop in my webserver `public_html`?

Comment: I mean, you could just create a `<script src="node_modules/three/index.js">` but that would mean having to push your node_modules folder to the server which is kinda janky. Really, you want your own `main.js` file which `import Three from 'three'` but then you need a module bundler like webpack or rollup and the accompanying config files.  Here is a guide  https://snipcart.com/blog/javascript-module-bundler

Comment: @andrew Thank you very much! I thought npm would be enough for this and didn't realise I need a module bundler.

Comment: npm is a package manager that is mainly meant to be used in combination with nodejs for server-side code. For client-side deployment, you need a bundler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Run "npm init", it will create package.json file in your package/project directory.

2 - Run "npm install three", it will install the external package and download it into "node_modules" folder.

3 - Create your own .js file. Example {in your package directory}/`<yourMainFile>`.js. Ensure in the package.json, you change the following attribute **"main"**: "`<yourMainFile>`.js".

4 - Refer to "three" package usage in https://www.npmjs.com/package/three.
and then write the sample code in `<yourMainFile>`.js

5 - If you want to test the result, run:
 $ node ./`<yourMainFile>`.js

- Use "./" if git bash cli.

6- If inside `<yourMainFile>`.js file contain console.log("hello or what ever result you want to display"), then you will see the text display in the console.

Comment: `three.js` is a library for rendering e.g. 3d sceneries based on that and on `what ... command I should run to "compile" my script for something to drop in my webserver public_html?` it is pretty likely that the OP would like to run the code in the browser.